# Storing credentials in a c# application

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords, password-protection

Hi everybody

i do not have a lot experience with c#. I want to write a very simple application, with must access a fileshare. The User (who executes the application) has NO access to that fileshare. So I need to use other credentials to access that fileshare. But I think it is not a good option to provide that credentials directly in the source code. I am thinking and thinking, but get no solution to that. Do you have a idea, how I could solve that problem? Is there a way to store the credentials somewhere, so that a possible attacker has problems to receive the used password?

Comment: Opinion based questions are off topic for SO I'm afraid. If I were you, look at encrypting it and maybe even using `SecureString`

Comment: I am not looking for opinions, I am more looking for a solution how to get a safe way to store passwords in generell. What would be the right question for that problem to get an answer? The problem in using a secure string is, I need to provide the key to decrypt it. If I am storing the key in the code, that would as bad as storing the password of my credentials directly in the code, would'nt it?

Comment: Yes, but the opinions are there because there's a hundred ways to achieve what you're doing. You need to do your own research and come back here if you have a specific programming problem you need answering.

Comment: Okay. I did research addressing that problem. But everything what I read is not realy practical. For example: If you use your guessed securestring: Please read my thinkings about that in my last answer.

Comment: You could try to obfuscate your code. I think there will be no perfect solution to access the fileshare without leaving access to the password as someone motivated enough will be able to retrieve it. Can you do a simple web service API which offers a limited accessto the fileshare? The API will contain the password, not the program, so it should be better but it will more complex to put in place.

Comment: The next possible solution what I got would be: writing a server component and a client component. The server component runs on a server and waits for requests. In that server component is the credential provided in the source code. But nobody has access to the server itself. The client asks the server component to get the informations provided in the share. The client itself has no access to it. That would be a possible solution I think, but it is may be "oversized" to access a simple file share. So aren't there easier solutions maybe?

Comment: I suggested encryption AND SecureString, Louhike has suggested a Web API, you might want to store your keys in a keyvault, you might want to have a popup on somebody's screen every time someone uses the app so they can enter a password. The point is that YOU need to first decide your solution and then we can help you with the implementation.

Comment: At a high level, this is solved by abstracting the secure resource within a distributed service. User must authenticate to the service, then the service accesses the protected resource. The "service" could be a web api, for example.

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData is quick and easy to use.  But arbitrarily protecting data from a user on their own machine is never going to work reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't both give the user the password and prevent them from having the password.  But every computing problem except for one, can be solved by adding an extra layer of indirection.  Create something that doesn't run on the users machine, that acts as a middleman between the file share and the user.  I would suggest using the WebDAV protocol.